# How can I move a variable outside the function in python

Tags: python

I have a variable `movie_index` that used in `show_data` function. I would like to move that variable outside the function

```
#Get the title of the movie that the user likes and store it into a variable.
def get_title_from_index(index):
    return df[df.Movie_id == index]["Title"].values[0]
    #return df[df.Image == index]["Image"].values[1]


#Find the row id / movie id of the movie the user likes and store it into a variable.
def get_index_from_title(title):
    return df[df.Title == title]["Movie_id"].values[0]
    #return df[df.Image == title]["Movie_id"].values[1]




from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("480x320")
ent = Entry(root)




def show_data():
    txt.delete(0.0, 'end')
    movie =ent.get()        #ent=Entry
    movie_index = get_index_from_title(movie)
    i=int(movie_index)
    Similar_movies = list( enumerate(cosine_sim[i]))
    # Sort the list of similar movies according to the similarity scores in descending order.
    sorted_similar_movies = sorted(Similar_movies,key = lambda x:x[1], reverse = True)
    #ph = PhotoImage(file='Images/' + df.Image[movie_index] + '.png')
    print(movie_index)
    # Create a loop to print the 11 movies from the sorted similar movies list.

    i=0;
    j=0;
    List =[None]*11
    for element in sorted_similar_movies:

            s=get_title_from_index(element[0])

            List[j]=s
            j=j+1;

            i=i+1;
            if i==11:
                break

for x in range(len(List) -1,-1,-1):
    txt.insert(0.0,List[x]+"\n") #space in textfield before show first Movie Name



l1 = Label(root, text="Enter Movie name: ")
l2 = Label(root, text="Top Suggtion Movies For You: ")
l3 = Label(root, width=200, height=200)


ph = PhotoImage(file='Images/' + df.Image[0] + '.png') #change this [0] into [movie_index]
resize_ph = ph.subsample(2, 2)

l1.grid(row=0)
l2.grid(row=2)
l3.grid(row=3, column=2)
l3.config(image=resize_ph, compound=CENTER)

ent.grid(row=0, column=2)

txt = Text(root, width=35, height=11, wrap=WORD)
txt.grid(row=3, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

btn = Button(root, text="Search", bg="blue", fg="white", command=show_data)
btn.grid(row=1, columnspan=3)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: At the end of `show_data` put `return movie_index`.  Then outside of the function say `movie_index = show_data()`.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\musta\PycharmProjects\Movies Recommendation System\CodeFile.py", line 94, in <module>
    movie_index = show_data()
  File "C:\Users\musta\PycharmProjects\Movies Recommendation System\CodeFile.py", line 60, in show_data
    txt.delete(0.0, 'end')
NameError: name 'txt' is not defined

Comment: Looks like that's because you reference a `txt` variable in `show_data` that's not defined yet (maybe because it's defined later in the program).  You'll need to think carefully about what order everything needs to happen in, since a lot of parts of this code depend on a lot of other parts.

Comment: Thanks, I solve it but i have new Error :)

Comment: Maybe start with a smaller piece of code?  You're hitting a lot of very basic programming errors on the way to getting this code to run at all, which suggests that you might have bitten off more than you can chew with this project.

Comment: yeah 
@Samwise is right

Answer (score 0):

this is easy I assume you area beginner, so here is the code

```
def show_data():
    #youur code
    return movie_index
```

and the use it like this

```
ph = PhotoImage(file='Images/' + df.Image[show_data()] + '.png')
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\musta\PycharmProjects\Movies Recommendation System\CodeFile.py", line 95, in <module>
    ph = PhotoImage(file='Images/' + df.Image[show_data()] + '.png')
  File "C:\Users\musta\PycharmProjects\Movies Recommendation System\CodeFile.py", line 62, in show_data
    movie_index = get_index_from_title(movie)
  File "C:\Users\musta\PycharmProjects\Movies Recommendation System\CodeFile.py", line 44, in get_index_from_title
    return df[df.Title == title]["Movie_id"].values[0]
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: get_index_from_title return df[df.Title == title]["Movie_id"].values[0] IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0  , bro this is a different function,irrelevant to your question